# automate index changing in a for loop

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that I extracted a list that I'm taking out of it.

I've tried to use list indexing to get the other items from the list but I'm getting this error.

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

```
    for name in data['athletes'][0:]['athlete']['displayName']:
        print(name)
```

If I don't use the colon in the indexing it extracts the first name.

Comment: You're going to need to show us enough code to reproduce the error, with some example data for it to work with. Otherwise there is no way to work out how to access your data structure correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying:

```
for name in data['athletes'][0:]['athlete']['displayName']:
    print(name)
```

Presumably `data['athletes'][0]` is a dictionary. But by saying `data['athletes'][0:]`, you are taking a `slice` of the `data['athletes']` list, in essence copying the entire list. Trying to extract a key value `'displayName'`, which is a string, from a list make no sense and hence your error (you can only index lists by integers). Of course, that was not your intention. You just want the zeroth element of the list, so remove the colon.

If each element of the list, `data['athletes']`, is a dictionary with key `athlete` that you are trying to display, then see the answer posted by Daniel Roseman (@DanielRoseman).

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want:

```
for athlete in data['athletes']
    print(athlete['athlete']['displayName']
```

but it's impossible to tell for sure without seeing your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of `data`, correct?

```
data: Dict[str, List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]]
```

Hence:

```
data['athletes'][0]: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]
data['athletes'][0:]: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]
```

When you slice `data['athletes']` (via `[0:]`), you get the `List`, which you can't index via a string.  When you get a particular element (via `[0]`), you get the first `Dict` inside the `List`.

Other answers have already suggested how to print the names.  If you wanted to turn them into a list, here's how you could do it via comprehension (I think this is sort of what you're trying to do with the slice):

```
names = [entry['athlete']['displayName'] for entry in data['athletes']]
```